# Use ELMAH to log database errors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I'm using ELMAH to handle the exceptions in my ASP.Net MVC project. I would like to use it to log errors like database connection timeout, query connection timeout and others. Is this possible with ELMAH?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you let the exception propogate out to the Elmah Web Module it will automatically log these exceptions.

You can however programatically log directly to Elmah, there are a couple of ways to do this:

You can use code like this in your catch clause in code:

```
try{....}
catch(Exception ex) { Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex); }
```

Another way of doing this is this:

```
Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(HttpContext.Current).Log(new Elmah.Error(ex));
```

I would however wrap this code into a more generic IErrorLogger style interface so that your lower level code doesn't need to have a hard dependency on Elmah itself

Comment: What is the difference, if any, between the two methods above?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is with ELMAH (never used it) but you can do all that with the MS Ent Libs, which are highly configurable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc467894.aspx

http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib5%20Beta1

Comment: He's already using ELMAH....suggesting he change his entire approach isn't a great call when it does indeed already do what he wants.